# How to extract patches of same size from images of different size and batch them together with tensorflow dataset api?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to make a tensorflow dataset api(tf version 1.8) for a set of images which are of different sizes. To do this, I am extracting patches of same size from the images and feeding it to my neural net.

The problem is in tf.extract_patches_from_images, the patches get stored in the channel dimension. As each image is of different size, number of patches are different for each image. Hence the shape of each resulting image is different. Hence I can't batch them together using tf dataset api.

Can someone suggest changes in my following modify_image function to tackle the issue?
 I guess separating the patches into different images and then batching them together would work. But I can't understand how to do that.

I want to scan the whole image, hence randomly selecting equal number of patches won't work for me.

```
def modify_image(image):
'''add preprocessing functions here'''
    image = tf.expand_dims(image,0)
    image = tf.extract_image_patches(
        image,
        ksizes=[1,patch_size,patch_size,1],
        strides=[1,patch_size,patch_size,1],
        rates=[1,1,1,1],
        padding='SAME',
        name=None
    )
    image = tf.reshape(image,shape=[-1,patch_size,patch_size,1])

return image;

def parse_function(image,labels):
    image= tf.read_file(image)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image)
    labels = tf.read_file(labels)
    labels = tf.image.decode_image(labels)
    image = modify_image(image)
    labels = modify_image(labels)
    return image,labels


def list_files(directory):
    files = glob.glob(directory)
    return files

def load_dataset(img_dir,labels_dir):
    images = list_files(img_dir)
    images = tf.constant(images)
    labels = list_files(labels_dir)
    labels = tf.constant(labels)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images,labels))
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
    return dataset




def make_batches(home_dir,img_dir,labels_dir,batch_size):

    img_dir = home_dir + img_dir
    labels_dir = home_dir +labels_dir

    dataset = load_dataset(img_dir,labels_dir)
    batched_dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return batched_dataset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`tf.contrib.data.unbatch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/unbatch) transformation might be helpful here, as it can separate the patches from a single image into different elements:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images,labels))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
patches_dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.unbatch())
batched_dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

Note that for `tf.contrib.data.unbatch()` to work, the number of patches in an image must match the number of elements/rows in `labels`. For example, if each patch should get the same label, you could achieve this by modifying `parse_function()` as follows to [`tf.tile()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) the labels an appropriate number of times:

```
def parse_function(images, labels):
  # ...
  return image, tf.tile([labels], tf.shape(image)[0:1])
```

Comment: Yes this fixed it. Thanks,